# Plotting recurrence relation defined by a function

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I am trying to show the graph of the sequence `u(n+1)=f(u(n))` for some function `f`. More specifically the goal is a graph like the following one :

[image: reccurence graph]

So far I have most of it, but I'm not sure how to properly define the different coordinates other calculating each term by hand to plot it, but other than that I'm not sure what to do. So here's what i got :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{function}{1}{\pgfmathparse{1+1/(#1)}}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        ymin = 0,
        ymax = 4,
        xmin = 0,
        xmax = 5,
        axis x line=bottom,
        axis y line = left,
        axis line style={->},
        xtick = {0,1,2,3,4},
        ytick = {1,2,3},
        ylabel = $y$,
        xlabel = $x$
        ]

    \addplot[domain=0:5, samples = 250, color=red]{function(\x)}
        node [pos=0.97, above] {$f(x)$};
    \addplot[domain=0:5, samples = 250]{\x}
        node [pos=0.6, below right] {$y=x$};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Which looks like this :

[image]

So I'd appreciate any help on how to add the relevant points to make the spirally figure on the first pic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so after a while I came up with a solution, using `pgfmathsetmacro` to set the coordinates. So here is the solution :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{function}{1}{\pgfmathparse{1+1/(#1)}}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
     ymin = 0,
ymax = 3,
xmin = 0,
xmax = 3,
axis x line=bottom,
axis y line = left,
axis line style={->},
xtick = {0,1,2},
ytick = {1,2},
ylabel = $y$,
xlabel = $x$
]
    \addplot[domain=0:3, samples = 250, color=blue]{function(\x)}
        node [pos=0.991, above right] {$f(x)$};
    \addplot[domain=0:3, samples = 250]{\x}
        node [pos=0.8, above left] {$y=x$};

    \def\xa{0.55}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\ya}{function(\xa)}
    \path (axis cs:\xa, \ya) coordinate (0);
    \path (axis cs:\ya, \ya) coordinate (1);
    \path (axis cs:\xa, 0) coordinate (2);

    \pgfmathsetmacro{\yb}{function(\ya)}
    \path (axis cs: \ya, \yb) coordinate (3);
    \path (axis cs: \yb, \yb) coordinate (4);
    \path (axis cs: \ya, 0) coordinate (10);

    \pgfmathsetmacro{\yc}{function(\yb)}
    \path (axis cs: \yb, \yc) coordinate (5);
    \path (axis cs: \yc, \yc) coordinate (6);
    \path (axis cs: \yb, 0) coordinate (7);

    \pgfmathsetmacro{\yd}{function(\yc)}
    \path (axis cs: \yc,\yd) coordinate (8);
    \path (axis cs: \yd,\yd) coordinate (9);
    \path (axis cs: \yc,0) coordinate (11);

\end{axis}
    \draw [color=red] (2) -- (0) -- (1) -- (3) -- (4) -- (5) -- (6) -- (8) -- (9);
    \draw [dashed, color=red] (0) -- (2) node[below] {$u_0$} (3) -- (10) node[below] {$u_1$};
    \draw [dashed, color=red] (5) -- (7) node[below] {$u_2$} (8) -- (11) node[below] {$u_3$}; 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

EDIT: I added the last two lines of the code above, I forgot to paste them the first time.

Answer (score 2):

It is very easy to recursively define functions. This can be done with the `math` library, and a prominent example is the one of Fibonacci numbers (p. 704 of pgfmanual v3.1.5). This has been used in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/447221). When I implement your function in the recursion I get a somewhat different output, though.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{math}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[evaluate={function myfun(\n) {
    if \n == 1 then { return 1;
    } else {
    return 1+1/myfun(\n-1);
    }; };}]
    \begin{axis}[
        ymin = 0,
        ymax = 4,
        xmin = 0,
        xmax = 5,
        axis x line=bottom,
        axis y line = left,
        axis line style={->},
        xtick = {0,1,2,3,4},
        ytick = {1,2,3},
        ylabel = $y$,
        xlabel = $x$
        ]

    \addplot[domain=0:5, samples = 250]{\x}
        node [pos=0.6, below right] {$y=x$};
    \addplot[domain=0:5, samples at={1,2,...,4}, color=red] {myfun(\x)}
        node [pos=0.97, above] {$f(x)$};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**EDIT**: After seeing your own answer I think I got it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{math}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[evaluate={function myfun(\n) {
    if \n == 1 then { return 1;
    } else {
    return 1+1/myfun(\n-1);
    }; };}]
    \begin{axis}[
        ymin = 0,
        ymax = 4,
        xmin = 0,
        xmax = 5,
        axis x line=bottom,
        axis y line = left,
        axis line style={->},
        xtick = {0,1,2,3,4},
        ytick = {1,2,3},
        ylabel = $y$,
        xlabel = $x$
        ]

    \addplot[domain=0:5, samples = 250]{\x}
        node [pos=0.6, below right] {$y=x$};
    \addplot[domain=0:5, samples at={1,2,...,10}, color=red] 
    ({myfun(int(\x/2+1/2))},{myfun(int(\x/2+1))})
        node [pos=0.97, above] {$f(x)$};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, indeed that's what I was going for, thanks!