# Sum of functions in \addplot

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

Let's say I have a function *f(x,k)* that depends on an integer *k*. I now want to use `pgfplots` to plot the function *g(x) = f(x,0) + f(x,1) + ... + f(x,n)*. How can I achieve this? Here is my code:

```
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
        axis lines=middle,
        xmin=-3, xmax=3,
        ymin=0, ymax=0.45,
        domain=-3:3,
        samples=100,
        smooth,
        xlabel=$x$,
        ylabel=$f(x)$,
        every axis y label/.style={at=(current axis.above origin),anchor=south},
        every axis x label/.style={at=(current axis.right of origin),anchor=west},
        xtick={-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3},
        ytick={0,0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4},
        xticklabels={-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3},
        yticklabels={0,0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4},
        enlargelimits=upper,
        clip=false
        ]
        
        \addplot[blue,thick] {x^2};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
```

What I want now is something like this:

```
        \addplot[blue,thick] {x^2+(x+1)^2+...+(x+100)^2};
```

Comment: Could you please make your code so we can compile it and explain what problem you're running into when you try what you've shown?

Comment: You could define a [recusive function](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/447221/47927) maybe, but I am quite sure that you will quickly get a "dimension too large" error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A little late but the short answer is to change your ymin and ymax: `ymin=305000, ymax=380000,`, adjust your y-axis labels as you see fit and change your function to `101*x^2+10100*x+338350`. The result running in Gummi is:
[image]

That answer might seem a bit strange, so go to a [Sage Cell Server](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/) and copy/paste the code below in

```
f=x^2
for i in range(1,101):
    f+=(x+i)^2
plot(f,-100,100)
```

then press `Evaluate` to get
[image]

We're dealing with what looks like a parabola and if you think about it, each of the 101 terms in the sum is a quadratic. The x^2 terms all have coefficient 1, so the function has 101x^2. The x terms are 2x, 4x, ..., 200x so the coefficient of x is 2(1+2+...+100). There's a formula for that 2(100/2)(1+100). The constant terms are 1^2+2^2+3^2+...+100^2. There's a formula for that as well (1/6)(100)(100+1)(2(100)+1). The Sage cell server can do the work, though:
[image]

In a more general case, which couldn't be reasoned through, you can use the [sagetex](https://ctan.org/pkg/sagetex) package, which relies on an open source computer algebra system to do the work. For this problem we could write

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{sagetex,amsmath,amssymb,tikz,pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{document}
\begin{sagesilent}
f=x^2
for i in range(1,101):
    f+=(x+i)^2
g=diff(f,x)
sol = solve(g==0,x)
\end{sagesilent}
Let $f(x,k)=\sum_{i=0}^{k}(x+i)^2$. For $k=100$ this becomes, after 
explanding and collecting like terms, $f(x,100)=\sage{simplify(expand(f))}$
which is a parabola. Since $f'(x)=\sage{g}$ the minimum value is when 
$x=\sage{sol[0].rhs()}$.
The plot of $f(x,100)$ looks like this over $[-3,3]$:
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[axis lines=middle,xmin=-3,  xmax=3,ymin=305000,ymax=380000,domain=-3:3,samples=100,  smooth,xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$f(x)$, every axis y label/.style={at=(current axis.above origin), anchor=south},every axis x label/.style={at=(current axis.right of origin), anchor=west},xtick={-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3},xticklabels={-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3},enlargelimits=upper, clip=false]
\addplot[blue,thick] {101*x^2+10100*x+338350};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

The result in Cocalc is:
[image]

Note that `f=x^2  for i in range(1,101):f+=(x+i)^2` defines the function (the last number, 101, doesn't get executed in Python). I can pull up the expansion `\sage{simplify(expand(f))}`, calculate its derivative, `g=diff(f,x)` and find the value of the minimum `sol = solve(g==0,x)`. These values can then be put into the LaTeX document.

Sage is not part of LaTeX so you will need a free Cocalc account or download Sage to your computer.

Answer (score 1):

An idea to start with maybe, but I am not sure whether this would also work with large numbers such as 100 ... Anyways: you could define a [recursive function](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/447221/47927) which would enable you to avoid repetitive code.

In the following code `compfun(5)` should be equivalent to `(x+0)^2+(x+1)^2+...+(x+5)^2`:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usetikzlibrary{math}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
            evaluate={
                function basefun(\i) {
                    return pow(x+\i,2);
                };
                function compfun(\j) {
                    if \j < 1 then {
                        return basefun(0);
                    } else {
                        return compfun(\j - 1) + basefun(\j);
                    };
                };
            },
        ]
        \begin{axis}[
            axis lines=middle,
            xmin=-10, xmax=10,
            ymin=0, ymax=50,
            samples=100,
            smooth,
            xlabel=$x$,
            ylabel=$f(x)$,
            every axis y label/.style={
                at=(current axis.above origin), 
                anchor=south
            },
            every axis x label/.style={
                at=(current axis.right of origin), 
                anchor=west
            },
            enlargelimits=upper,
        ]
        \addplot[blue, thick] {compfun(5)};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I am truly grateful!